# Easy way to get the keys in a map in alphabetical order

Tags: sorting, dictionary, go

In Go, what's the easiest way to get the keys in a map sorted alphabetically? This is the shortest way I can do it:

```
package main

import "container/vector"
import "fmt"
import "sort"

func main() {
    m := map[string]string {"b":"15", "z":"123123", "x":"sdf", "a":"12"}
    var keys vector.StringVector;
    for k,_ := range ( m ) {
            keys.Push(k)
    }
    sort.Sort( &keys )
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", keys)
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You are sorting an array of strings using StringVector. To minimize overhead, you could sort an array of strings.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{"b": "15", "z": "123123", "x": "sdf", "a": "12"}
    mk := make([]string, len(m))
    i := 0
    for k, _ := range m {
        mk[i] = k
        i++
    }
    sort.Strings(mk)
    fmt.Println(mk)
}
```

Output:

```
[a b x z]
```

Comment: The `SortStrings` func seems to be gone in current (Mar 2012) Go.  It seems to just be `Strings` now (i.e., `sort.Strings(mk)`)

Answer (score 17):

That would be most elegant method:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{"b": "15", "z": "123123", "x": "sdf", "a": "12"}
    keys := make([]string, 0, len(m))
    for key := range m {
        keys = append(keys, key)
    }
    sort.Strings(keys)
    fmt.Println(keys)
}
```

Comment: BenchmarkFirst-4      5000000        367 ns/op       96 B/op        2 allocs/op
BenchmarkSecond-4     5000000        352 ns/op       96 B/op        2 allocs/op
PASS
ok   slice 4.383s